# Scope of variables when including files using php

Tags: php, oop

I have a situation where I have 2 files, `File A` and `File B1`. I then have 20 other scripts including these files. File A contains some class that are instantiated in File B.

If a variable changes within a class in File A will it change for ALL 20 scripts?

I have a very weird issue where something is updating and when I put some debug code on each point where that variable is changed, it doesn't trigger. That is the reason for the question as it seems like one of the other 19 files including these is causing a change ...

To Clarify:

I am not including a file more than once. I have 20 different scripts running separately that include the SAME file (only do it once). This is so I only need to update 1 file when I make a change and all the other files use that source. If a public var is changed within a class in that ONE file, is it changed for all the 20 files.

THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

An included file is included in whatever scope it is included in.

If you include a file in the topmost scope, then it has that scope.
If you include a file via a function, then it's scope is within that function.

Comment: So if script 1 changes a var in File A, then script 20 will see that new value when it includes File A?

Comment: Well, no, you shouldn't include a file more than once, by using  include_once() or require_once(), which will only include the file once regardless of how many times it's called.  But lets say you have FileA that looks like `$a = 2; include_once('FileB'); include_once('FileC');` and FileB that does `$a = 5;` and FileC that does `echo $a`, then the output would be `5`.  Basically, an included/required file is exactly like if you had taken that code or whatever in that included file and literally copy/pasted it into the file that is doing the including at the point of the include() call.

Comment: I don't think I have been clear about my includes. I am not including a file more than once. I have 20 different scripts running separately that include the SAME file (only do it once). This is so I only need to update 1 file when I make a change and all the other files use that source. If a global var is changed within that ONE file, is it changed for all? Sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: If it is manually changed, i.e. in a text editor, yes.  If it's changed by script, no.  Every time the file is included it is included in original form.  `$a` will always start out equal to `2` (using the last example I gave.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 20 scripts that include "File A" every time in separates, so every instance will change his own "File A" class, what you can do is use include_once or require_once, then if you already include File A the next include for the same file will be not called, it useful if you already include file and you don't remember, now for the "Scope issue" if you create functionA inside functionB so only inside functionB you could use functionA it work the same for files, if you include fileA inside fileB and fileC inside fileB it will work greate, but if you do this include inside inner scope (like method, class) this file could not access anything out of the scope.